# Помогите с установкой MadelineProto

Tags: php, madelineproto

Пытаюсь все сделать по [этой инструкции](https://coderun.ru/blog/kak-parsit-telegram-kanal-pri-pomoshhi-php/)

Не понятен вот этот момнет:

> Следующее что нам надо, это скачать проект https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto к себе в отдельную папку на хостинге **и при помощи composer установить все зависимости**.

Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен за развернутый ответ с примерами. Хотелось бы простого решения.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите простого решения, то установите без composer
https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/INSTALLATION.html#simple

Comment: а как потом использовать есть пример? (например получить посты из канала)

Comment: https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/#getting-started-now-fully-async

Comment: для получения постов из канала используйте методы из документации

Comment: https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/messages.search.html  - получает сообщения, можно добавить фильтр